# separating fields not aligned from a pipe delimited file

Tags: pipe, command, csv

I have a file which has entries separated by | and tab.

```
#Name   Length  Bases   Coverage    Reads   RPKM    Frags   FPKM
ENST00000423372.3|ENSG00000237683.5|-|-|AL627309.1-201|AL627309.1|2661|UTR5:1-70|CDS:71-850|UTR3:851-2661|  2661    1989878 747.7933    13178   33.6603 6589    33.6603
ENST00000426406.1|ENSG00000235249.1|OTTHUMG00000002860.1|OTTHUMT00000007999.1|OR4F29-001|OR4F29|995|UTR5:1-19|CDS:20-958|UTR3:959-995|  995 302 0.3035  2   0.0137  1   0.0137
ENST00000599533.1|ENSG00000269831.1|-|-|AL669831.1-201|AL669831.1|129|CDS:1-129|    129 52548   407.3488    348 18.3359 174 18.3359
ENST00000437963.1|ENSG00000187634.6|OTTHUMG00000040719.8|OTTHUMT00000097862.3|SAMD11-003|SAMD11|387|UTR5:1-60|CDS:61-387|   387 302 0.7804  2   0.0351  1   0.0351
ENST00000342066.3|ENSG00000187634.6|OTTHUMG00000040719.8|OTTHUMT00000276866.2|SAMD11-010|SAMD11|2551|UTR5:1-83|CDS:84-2129|UTR3:2130-2551|  2551    17818   6.9847  118 0.3144  59  0.3144
ENST00000341065.4|ENSG00000187634.6|OTTHUMG00000040719.8|OTTHUMT00000097860.4|SAMD11-001|SAMD11|2191|CDS:1-1769|UTR3:1770-2191| 2191    12080   5.5135  80  0.2482  40  0.2482
ENST00000455979.1|ENSG00000187634.6|OTTHUMG00000040719.8|OTTHUMT00000097863.4|SAMD11-004|SAMD11|1731|CDS:1-1625|UTR3:1626-1731| 1731    302 0.1745  2   0.0079  1   0.0079
ENST00000598827.1|ENSG00000268179.1|-|-|AL645608.1-201|AL645608.1|336|CDS:1-336|    336 302 0.8988  2   0.0405  1   0.0405
```

I want the output as

```
AL627309.1  33.6603
OR4F29      0.0137
AL669831.1  18.3359
SAMD11  0.0351
SAMD11  0.3144
SAMD11  0.2482
SAMD11  0.0079
     
separated by tab.
```

I replaced all the | by tabs using `tr '|' "\t" < input.file`
but the resulting file shows this since the fields are variable.

```
#Name                                       Length  Bases   Coverage    Reads   RPKM    Frags   FPKM    
ENST00000423372.3   ENSG00000237683.5   -   -   AL627309.1-201  AL627309.1  2661    UTR5:1-70   CDS:71-850  UTR3:851-2661       2661    1989878 747.7933    13178   33.6603 6589    33.6603
ENST00000426406.1   ENSG00000235249.1   OTTHUMG00000002860.1    OTTHUMT00000007999.1    OR4F29-001  OR4F29  995 UTR5:1-19   CDS:20-958  UTR3:959-995        995 302 0.3035  2   0.0137  1   0.0137
ENST00000599533.1   ENSG00000269831.1   -   -   AL669831.1-201  AL669831.1  129 CDS:1-129       129 52548   407.3488    348 18.3359 174 18.3359     
ENST00000437963.1   ENSG00000187634.6   OTTHUMG00000040719.8    OTTHUMT00000097862.3    SAMD11-003  SAMD11  387 UTR5:1-60   CDS:61-387      387 302 0.7804  2   0.0351  1   0.0351  
ENST00000342066.3   ENSG00000187634.6   OTTHUMG00000040719.8    OTTHUMT00000276866.2    SAMD11-010  SAMD11  2551    UTR5:1-83   CDS:84-2129 UTR3:2130-2551      2551    17818   6.9847  118 0.3144  59  0.3144
ENST00000341065.4   ENSG00000187634.6   OTTHUMG00000040719.8    OTTHUMT00000097860.4    SAMD11-001  SAMD11  2191    CDS:1-1769  UTR3:1770-2191      2191    12080   5.5135  80  0.2482  40  0.2482  
ENST00000455979.1   ENSG00000187634.6   OTTHUMG00000040719.8    OTTHUMT00000097863.4    SAMD11-004  SAMD11  1731    CDS:1-1625  UTR3:1626-1731      1731    302 0.1745  2   0.0079  1   0.0079
```

Kindly guide me if there is a elegant way to do this.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem some more: if you want a single tab between entries, than this cannot be "neatly sorted" (from a readers view), if you want it in "neat columns", the separators will change in count.

Comment: Is the header actually part of the file? It is very strange to see the header using one character as a separator and the data using another. Also, what is the problem with the final output you show? Yes, the columns are not aligned, but that is normal since as you say they are of variable lengths. Do you also want them to be aligned?

Comment: This? `tr '|' '\t' < myfile | column -t`. But there is something wrong with your input data, it has different column count per row.

Comment: @terdon yes I want to align the columns the way I showed.

Comment: @roaima I used the column -t command but it did not produce the desired output.

Comment: OK, so this is only for display purposes right? Because if you align the columns, you break the file for any downstream processing. Can you also confirm that the header uses a different field separator and tell us what is used in the header? Finally what do you actually want? Your first output shows a modified 5th field (without the `-` and what follows it) and the last field of every line, but your second output shows the whole file so it isn't clear which of the two you need.

Comment: @terdon One can ignore the header. The first output is the way I want to output to be as the other columns in betwen are not important for the processing of data (too much redundant information). The second output was when I tried using the command . It did away with the pipe delimiter but completely generated variable column lengths which I found difficult to align even with awk.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I've got the tabs vs spaces correct, this should work. Remove the `column -t` if you're going to be piping this into any other tool so that you get exactly one tab between the fields

```
awk -F'[|\t]' '!/^#/{printf "%s\t%s\n", $6, $NF}' your_datafile | column -t
```

This splits the data at either `|` or a tab, numbering the columns from 1. `!/^#/` matches any line that does not begin with `#` (the intention is to skip any header rows, so we could have used `NR>1`). The `$6` construct picks the sixth field; `$NF` picks the last field regardless of its field number.

Output using your example datafile,

```
AL627309.1  33.6603
OR4F29      0.0137
AL669831.1  18.3359
SAMD11      0.0351
SAMD11      0.3144
SAMD11      0.2482
SAMD11      0.0079
AL645608.1  0.0405
```

Comment: which was the input file used here.Kindly let me know.

Comment: Your input file in the question

Comment: it works ...thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1738234 if this answer works for you please accept the answer with ✔

Answer (score 2):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/), grep and paste

```
paste <(<input.txt tail -n +2 | grep -oP '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$') \
<(<input.txt tail -n +2 | mlr --nidx --ifs "|" unsparsify then clean-whitespace then cut -f 6)
```

you will have

```
AL627309.1      33.6603
OR4F29  0.0137
AL669831.1      18.3359
SAMD11  0.0351
SAMD11  0.3144
SAMD11  0.2482
SAMD11  0.0079
AL645608.1      0.0405
```

Your input is weird. You should have specified in the request that the last field you wanted was the last numeric value of each row and not a specific field

```
+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------------+------+------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1                 | 2                 | 3                    | 4                    | 5              | 6          | 7    | 8          | 9                                          | 10                                    | 11                                               |
+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------------+------+------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| ENST00000423372.3 | ENSG00000237683.5 | -                    | -                    | AL627309.1-201 | AL627309.1 | 2661 | UTR5:1-70  | CDS:71-850                                 | UTR3:851-2661                         | 2661 1989878 747.7933 13178 33.6603 6589 33.6603 |
| ENST00000426406.1 | ENSG00000235249.1 | OTTHUMG00000002860.1 | OTTHUMT00000007999.1 | OR4F29-001     | OR4F29     | 995  | UTR5:1-19  | CDS:20-958                                 | UTR3:959-995                          | 995 302 0.3035 2 0.0137 1 0.0137                 |
| ENST00000599533.1 | ENSG00000269831.1 | -                    | -                    | AL669831.1-201 | AL669831.1 | 129  | CDS:1-129  | 129 52548 407.3488 348 18.3359 174 18.3359 |                                       |                                                  |
| ENST00000437963.1 | ENSG00000187634.6 | OTTHUMG00000040719.8 | OTTHUMT00000097862.3 | SAMD11-003     | SAMD11     | 387  | UTR5:1-60  | CDS:61-387                                 | 387 302 0.7804 2 0.0351 1 0.0351      |                                                  |
| ENST00000342066.3 | ENSG00000187634.6 | OTTHUMG00000040719.8 | OTTHUMT00000276866.2 | SAMD11-010     | SAMD11     | 2551 | UTR5:1-83  | CDS:84-2129                                | UTR3:2130-2551                        | 2551 17818 6.9847 118 0.3144 59 0.3144           |
| ENST00000341065.4 | ENSG00000187634.6 | OTTHUMG00000040719.8 | OTTHUMT00000097860.4 | SAMD11-001     | SAMD11     | 2191 | CDS:1-1769 | UTR3:1770-2191                             | 2191 12080 5.5135 80 0.2482 40 0.2482 |                                                  |
| ENST00000455979.1 | ENSG00000187634.6 | OTTHUMG00000040719.8 | OTTHUMT00000097863.4 | SAMD11-004     | SAMD11     | 1731 | CDS:1-1625 | UTR3:1626-1731                             | 1731 302 0.1745 2 0.0079 1 0.0079     |                                                  |
| ENST00000598827.1 | ENSG00000268179.1 | -                    | -                    | AL645608.1-201 | AL645608.1 | 336  | CDS:1-336  | 336 302 0.8988 2 0.0405 1 0.0405           |                                       |                                                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+------------+------+------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

We can easily pick out the 6th pipe-delimited field using `cut`, but the 8th field (`FPKM`) seems to contain more than one pipe-delimited piece of data, causing the whole table to become misaligned.

So for simplicity, we use `cut` for the 6th field on and then use `sed` to delete everything on each line from the first `|` to the last tab.

```
$ cut -d '|' -f 6- file | sed -n '1!s/|.*\([[:blank:]]\)/\1/p'
AL627309.1      33.6603
OR4F29  0.0137
AL669831.1      18.3359
SAMD11  0.0351
SAMD11  0.3144
SAMD11  0.2482
SAMD11  0.0079
AL645608.1      0.0405
```

The way I'm using `sed` above makes it skip the header line completely, and then allows for either a space or a tab character in front of the final piece of data on the line.  I'm reusing that space-or-tab character for the delimiter between the last field and the original 6th field.

In a shell supporting process substitutions using `<(...)`, you may use the following to reformat the original data into a tab-delimited set, with the problematic column retaining its pipe-delimiters.  I'm running it through `column -t` at the end for presentation purposes, but you should remove that if you need tab-delimited output.

```bsh
paste <( cut -d '|' -f -7 file | tr '|' '\t' ) \
      <( cut -d '|' -f 8- file | sed 's/|[[:blank:]]//' ) |
tail -n +2 | column -t
```